# final line of output not writing to file

Tags: python-3.x, file-io

I am writing a program to count the frequency of various length nucleotide pattern occurrences in DNA files.  I am using Python 3.3.3.  My question has to do with output to a text file being incomplete and not matching the output using the print command.

This is my second edit of the question, and I hope this makes the problem clear.  In the code below, if the open() line is removed, the output to the IDE is four lines with one letter on each line.  If I leave the line in, the external output file has three lines with one letter each, the fourth character does not print.  Using the output command results in the same incomplete output file.

```
import sys
H = "agtc"
pattern = ""
for x in H:
    count = 1
    if x == 'a' or x == 'g' or x == 't' or x == 'c':
        while count < 5:
            pattern = x
            count += 1
    sys.stdout = open ('C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/tetramers.txt', 'a')
    print (pattern)
```

Comment: Hi sph. That's a lot of code for a Stack Overflow question! You'd probably get better answers (and maybe even find the problem yourself) if you trimmed down the code even further -- right down to the bare minimum that reproduces the problem (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: I have simplified the code as much as I can to still illustrate the problem.  As I originally said, I am self-taught and what I have may be inefficient, but it is the only way I can figure how to do what I want to do.  I have looked at many posts on stack overflow and have seen many comments asking for more details, so I thought more would be better.  Thank you for the recommendation, and I hope what I provided this time is better.

Comment: Great work, you've reduced the complexity a lot -- which means that it's easier for somebody to look over the code and try to help. In particular, it's good that you hard-coded the input (because your your question isn't about the input format). The code is still pretty complex, though -- I wonder if there's any more logic (`if`s, `for`s and `while`s) that you could replace?

Comment: By the way, now that it's more self-contained, I notice a few areas that might be worth investigating: I notice your call to `open()` is inside a loop -- what happens if you open first and only `write` in the loop? I notice that the expression in `print()` (which you say works) is different to the expression in `write()` (which you say has a problem). If you change the `print()` to match, does it show the same problem?

Comment: I moved the open() statement outside the main for loop and the output file was empty.  I moved it to between the two for loops, between the second for and the if, immediately after the if, after the if but before the while, and inside the while.  In each of those cases, I get the same output, showing the count of a, g, and t, but not c.  I have tried replacing the loops, as you suggested, but have not yet found a way to simplify.

Comment: Wow, it's much clearer now. I can reproduce the problem on my computer, which means I can help you. I'm writing up an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single-word answer is "**buffering**", and the solution is the `with` keyword (and/or `buffering=1`) but let me walk you through a process to help figure this kind of thing out.

I ran your example with the command-line Python interpreter on my computer and it did not exhibit the problem (the output file contained all four lines). When you edited your question and mentioned "the output to the IDE", I realised this might be an environment difference. I tried the same code in the "IDLE" IDE that comes with Python and I saw the problem you describe (the output file contained only three lines).

The problem is file output, so I focused on finding just the file output code:

```
import sys
H = "agtc"
...
for x in H:
    ...
    if ...:
        ...
    ...
    sys.stdout = open ('C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/tetramers.txt', 'a')
    print (...)
```

which we can simplify to:

```
import sys

for x in "agtc":
    sys.stdout = open('C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/tetramers.txt', 'a')
    print(...)
```

Now that it's like that, it's easier to see that the code is opening a file four times, but never explicitly closing it.

Now, when I first saw `sys.stdout = ...` I was suspicious of that. Re-assigning stdout isn't something I do every day, and I wondered if that might be part of the problem. I tried `open`ing a file without changing stdout:

```
for x in "agtc":
    f = open('output.txt', 'a')
    print(x, file=f)
```

It gives the same output (three lines instead of four), so I guess it's not a problem with reassigning stdout. That's still one less complexity to worry about, though, so we'll keep the simpler code while we figure it out.

So what's next? I think I know, but I'll keep that to myself for the moment -- this answer is to demonstrate the thought process and give you some debugging techniques that you can use in the future to pin down problems that have nothing to do with files and buffers.

You mentioned in the comments that moving `open()` to outside the loop resulted in an empty file. That's a hint that something's amiss: opening the file every time should be slower, but not have different output.

Let's confirm that:

```
f = open('output.txt', 'a')
for x in "agtc":    
    print(x, file=f)
```

Just like you said... No output. (Again, that's no output when run from IDLE. It produces all four lines from my command-line Python.)

So when the `open()` happens *before* the four `print()` calls, there's no output, but when `open()` happens *between* the four `print()` calls there's... some output, but not all of it. Sounds like a "fencepost" error. Let's "unroll" the `for` loop:

```
f = open('output.txt', 'a')
print("a", file=f)
f = open('output.txt', 'a')
print("g", file=f)
f = open('output.txt', 'a')
print("c", file=f)
f = open('output.txt', 'a')
print("t", file=f)
```

A loop should behave the same when it's unrolled, and indeed this one produces the same three lines as before -- the `print()` calls *between* the `open()` calls. What happens if we make sure *all* of the `print()` calls are between `open()` calls?

```
f = open('output.txt', 'a')
print("a", file=f)
f = open('output.txt', 'a')
print("g", file=f)
f = open('output.txt', 'a')
print("c", file=f)
f = open('output.txt', 'a')
print("t", file=f)
f = open('output.txt', 'a')
```

All four lines are in the output. Now, clearly, calling `open()` before and after every `print()` is not a useful end-solution, but it's a useful stepping-stone we can use to understand some of the mysteries we've encountered. Let's go back to the example where we opened the file first, then looped over writing. It came out blank before, but what if we applied our new knowledge that `print()` seems to work when *between* two `open()`s?

```
f = open('output.txt', 'a')
print("a", file=f)
print("g", file=f)
print("c", file=f)
print("t", file=f)
f = open('output.txt', 'a')
```

All the lines are output. So it's not that each `print()` needs two `open()` calls. Good. But not that good, because clearly it doesn't make much sense to call `open()` *after* you're finished doing all your work. It would make more sense to *close* a file after you're done. Wait a moment...

Do file objects have a `close()` method or something like it? Let's check the documentation. The official Python 3 tutorial's "[Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)" section says:

> When you’re done with a file, call f.close() to close it and free up any system resources taken up by the open file. After calling f.close(), attempts to use the file object will automatically fail.

So there *is* a `close()` method. Let's try that in our code:

```
f = open('output.txt', 'a')
print("a", file=f)
print("g", file=f)
print("c", file=f)
print("t", file=f)
f.close()
```

Hey, look at that. It works *and* makes sense. Much better.

---

The next paragraph in the tutorial is pretty interesting too:

> It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.

If you're just getting started, that new keyword might be a bit confusing for now -- that's fine, you can clean up after yourself manually until you're ready. It looks a bit like this:

```
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    print("a", file=f)
    print("g", file=f)
    print("c", file=f)
    print("t", file=f)
```

---

There's still an unresolved mystery: why *didn't* the problem show up with my command-line Python too? Is the Python running in IDLE somehow more sensitive to leaving files open? That's worth investigating, but this answer is long enough as it is (and probably covers more than you wanted anyway).